# Two Group By Dataset Spark Java API

Tags: java, apache-spark, apache-spark-sql, hdfs

I'm new in Spark Java API. I want to apply two groupby (Sum et Count ) to my Dataset.

My Ds is something like this.

```
+---------+------------+
|  account|    amount  |
+---------+------------+
| aaaaaa  |   1000     |
| aaaaaa  |   2000     |
| bbbbbb  |   4000     |
| cccccc  |   5000     |
| cccccc  |   3000     |
```

I want to get a **Dataset** Like this.

```
 +---------+------------+------------+
 | account |    sum     |    count   |
 +---------+------------+------------+
 | aaaaaa  |   3000     |   2        |
 | bbbbbb  |   4000     |   1        |
 | cccccc  |   8000     |   2        |
```

Can someone please, guide me with an expression in Spark Java API

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
df.groupBy("account").agg(sum("amount"),count("account")).show()
```